# Do we fast when someone trips and falls while holding a Sefer Torah?

Tags: minhag, fast-days, sefer-torah

When dropping a Sefer Torah, the custom is to fast, but what is the minhag if I trip and fall while holding a Sefer Torah?

Comment: Why should this be any different? Either way it’s an accident (hopefully).

Comment: Welcome! To MY!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Shonrabino in this imaginary event, did the person holding the Torah manage to avoid having the Sefer come into contact with the floor? That would be an interesting question indeed!

Comment: @JoshK That's not imaginary. I've seen two case were people tripped but landed sitting down still holding the Torah and it did not hit the floor.

Comment: @DanF Fascinating. So was it a case of "no harm, no foul" or did you fast as if it had hit the floor?

Comment: @JoshK From what I recall, the majority of people in the shul were 65+. I don't think anyone would have fasted regardless of what would have happened.

Answer (score -4):

The concept of fasting after dropping a Sefer Torah during a minyon , c”v, is a mitzvah, not a custom (minhag).

Regarding fasting, in general in this generation, the practice is to be lenient.

If you go to a Posek today and ask such a question, if there is a way to release you from, or to make an exchange for, or to minimize your fasting, that is likely the reply you will receive.